# Pandas: change object's value

Tags: python, pandas

Python newbie here having problems to find a solution.

My data is quite simple: date column (lots of years) and flow column. Wanted to plot time vs flow yearly, so I created an object with the year I want to plot followed by a line to filter the desired year out the original data.

```
dailyq = pd.read_csv('Meandq.csv', 
                      sep=';')
year= '2022'
qy= dailyq.loc[(dailyq['Date'] >= '01/01/' + year) & 
                (dailyq['Date'] <= '31/12/' + year)]
```

With this method, I have to change manually the value of year, but I feel dork when I have to process long time series (i.e. from 1950 to 2022), so I wanted to use a loop to change automatically the year. Some ideas, please?

I just tried some loops but I really can't find the logic to make Python understand me.

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop year as an integer and cast it as a string while querying, like this.

```
dailyq = pd.read_csv('Meandq.csv', sep=';')

for year in range(1950, 2023):
    qy= dailyq.loc[(dailyq['Date'] >= '01/01/'+str(year)) & (dailyq['Date'] <= '31/12/'+str(year))]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With this method, I'm only getting one year data. I.e., if I establish a range(2012, 2021), it only responds with the 2019's data. So sorry if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: if you're performing any operation, try doing that inside the loop or store the results in a list for later processing. As variable `qy` will be overwritten upon each loop

Comment: I was operating inside the loop, but I had an error saving the plots. Now everything is fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: Alright, happy to help.